# Image in listview via database+assets

Tags: android, image, listview, assets

I have a database which has a name of an animal, and in an other column a sound of the animal.
The listview works fine, and now I would like to extend it with an image out of the assets.
For this I've read about how to get the assets data and use it.
An example I've tried worked fine for me.
Now I want this "assets" code (at least I think I want this) in the extended BaseAdapter class.
Unfortunately I'm doing something wrong as I can't use the getAssets() in the BaseAdapter.

The problem starts in the try-catch block: " getAssets " doesn't get recognized

Which way would I think of solving this?
Creating another class in which this assets code can run in an extended "Activity"?
Or are there better ways of showing an image via database info in a listview?

Thank you for your support in my quest to get familiar with Android / Java.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get view reference
    View view = convertView;
    // if null 
    if(view == null) {
        // inflate new layout
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
        // create a holder
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        // find controls
        holder.txtName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtPicture = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtPicture);
        // set data structure to view
        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    // get selected user info
    UserInfo userInfo = mListUserInfo.get(position);
    // if not null
    if(userInfo != null) {
        // query data structure
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        // set data to display
        holder.txtName.setText(userInfo.getName() + ", " + userInfo.getPicture() );

        try {
                        // get input stream
                        InputStream ips = getAssets().open( userInfo.getPicture() + ".jpg");
                        Log.d("Imageloading", "Reading: " + ips);
                        // load image as Drawable
                        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ips, null);
                        // set image to ImageView

                        holder.txtPicture.setImageDrawable( d );
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex) {
                        Log.e("Imageloading", "Could not load '" + ex.getMessage()+ "'!");
                    }
    }       

    // return view
    return view;
}
```

I've just edited the code.
To solve the getAssets() thing I've done the following:

> holder.txtPicture.setImageDrawable( getSomePicture(null, userInfo.getPicture() + ".jpg") );

```
public Drawable getSomePicture(Context myContext, String WhichPicture) throws IOException {
 // get input stream
    InputStream ips = myContext.getAssets().open( WhichPicture );
    Log.d("Imageloading", "Reading: " + ips);
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ips, null);
return d;    
}
```

This still is not the solution, researching some more....
Found an interesting source for [Lazy Loading](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to call getAssets() function in non-activity class you need reference to Context. In your updated code you called function 'getSomePicture()' and passed null to myContext parameter. that means your code will fail because you have myContext.getAssets() later in your method code.

try to do this in your getView method:

```
Context context = getContext();

holder.txtPicture.setImageDrawable( getSomePicture(context, userInfo.getPicture() + ".jpg") );
```

Comment: I've tried this also, but I get the message "The method getContext() is undefined"

Comment: Context MyContext;   and MyContext.getAssets() gives green light :)  Going to check of the code will work.

Comment: The code itself is not working right now. Got some homework to do and will get back when it works. Reading the logs, it stops at the MyContext.getAssets line :(

Comment: Ok, solved my problem. The code itself was "ok".
I've send the context from the upper class down to the extended BaseAdapter class and put in in the MyContext variable. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have access to the getAssets() method because that is a method that only the Context (and it's subclass, Activity) have. What I find is easiest here is to make your BaseAdapter subclasses private inner classes of the Activity in which it is to be used. That way, you'll have access to the getAssets() method.

Here is what this might look like:

```
public class YourExampleActivity extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    }

    private class YourListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // get view reference
            View view = convertView;
            // if null 
            if(view == null) {
                // inflate new layout
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
                // create a holder
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                // find controls
                holder.txtName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                holder.txtPicture = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtPicture);
                // set data structure to view
                view.setTag(holder);
            }

            // get selected user info
            UserInfo userInfo = mListUserInfo.get(position);
            // if not null
            if(userInfo != null) {
                // query data structure
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                // set data to display
                holder.txtName.setText(userInfo.getName() + ", " + userInfo.getPicture() );

                try {
                    // get input stream
                    InputStream ips = getAssets().open( userInfo.getPicture() + ".jpg");
                    Log.d("Imageloading", "Reading: " + ips);
                    // load image as Drawable
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ips, null);
                    // set image to ImageView

                    holder.txtPicture.setImageDrawable( d );
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    Log.e("Imageloading", "Could not load '" + ex.getMessage()+ "'!");
                }
            }       

            // return view
            return view;
        } 

       // Override other key methods of BaseAdapter here
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, you could take in a Context object in the constructor when the BaseAdapter subclass is instantiated, and keep a reference to that with which to call getAssets() on. Please post a comment if you need an example of this.

Comment: I think your code also could work, but I just have chosen to not put all the code in an extended Activity class to clean things up and make my code readable. Not sure if it's the best way...

Comment: Either way will work for you @Gaston, it sounds like you have chosen the second suggestion I made based on what you said above, passing the context object in and storing it as myContext. That way works just as well.